# why does the easy-in-out not work for the contact form part?

Tags: html, css

I can not figure out why ease-in and -out does not work for the contact form. it works for the header but not the contact form. My contact form is in a div called contact-form. stackoverflow is saying that i need add more details but i am not sure what to write so i am just going to write some random stuff.  please help thank you

This is the html code

```
<div class="contact-form">

  <form id="contact-form" method="post" actipn="">
     <input name="name" type="text" class= "form-control" placeholder="Your Name" required><br><br>
     <input name="email" type="text" class= "form-control" placeholder="Your Email" required><br><br>
     <textarea name="message" class="form-control" cols="20" rows="6" placeholder="Message"></textarea><br><br>
     <input type="submit" class="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE">

  </form>
</div>
```

This is the css code

```
header{
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
   position: absolute;
   text-align: center;
   top:20%;
   display: inline;
   transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.contact-form{

    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;

}




.form-control{
    width: 500px;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blueviolet;
    color: blueviolet;
    font-size: 18px;

}


input{
    height: 45px;
}
.submit{
    position: relative;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    border: none;
    width: auto;

}

.submit:hover{

    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to transition the whole contact form or just the elements inside of it? It might be helpful if you put all of your code, including the header, in a Codepen for us to see. https://codepen.io/

Comment: @jack be clear with your requirements. Whatever i understood i added my answer. But when you are asking any question be clear what is your actual requirement and never use same names for class and id because it will; create a confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
/* defaults */

html,
body {
 height: 100%;
}

html {
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-size: 24px;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
 -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 line-height: 1.5;
 background-color: #e7e7e7;
 font-family: Roboto, Helvectica, Arial, sans-serif;
 color: #333;
}


/* headers */

h1 {
 font-family: "Roboto Slab", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
 font-size: 2em;
}


/* form elements */

label {
 display: block;
}

select,
textarea,
input {
 max-width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: inherit;
 font-weight: inherit;
 font-size: inherit;
 color: inherit;
}

input[type=submit] {
 border: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}


/* vertical align snippet */

.va-cont {
 display: table;
 table-layout: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.va-inn {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
}


/* styles */

.form-container {
 width: 80%;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: auto;
}

.form-heading {
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 1.2em;
 text-align: center;
}

.form-heading-highlight {
 color: #009688;
}

.form-row {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 30px;
}

.form-label {
 position: absolute;
 top: 17px;
 left: 20px;
 color: #999;
 cursor: text;
   transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.form-textbox,
.form-submit {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 20px;
}

.form-textbox { 
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.form-textbox:focus ~ .form-label,
.form-textbox:valid ~ .form-label {
 top: -1.5em;
 left: 0;
 font-size: .8em;
 color: inherit;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.form-submit {
 background-color: #009688;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #fff;
 transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.form-submit:hover {
 opacity: .75;
}


/* media queries */

@media only screen and (max-width:1366px) {
 .form-container {
  width: 70%;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1024px) {
 body {
  font-size: .85em;
 }
 .form-container {
  width: 80%;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
 body {
  font-size: .7em;
 }
 .form-container {
  width: 90%;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
 .form-container {
  width: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="va-cont">
 <div class="va-inn">
  <form onsubmit="" class="form-container">
   <h1 class="form-heading">
    <span class="form-heading-highlight">CSS transitions</span><br>Form label placeholders
   </h1>
   <div class="form-row">
    <input type="text" id="form-email" class="form-textbox" required>
    <label for="form-email" class="form-label">Email address</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-row">
    <input type="password" id="form-password" class="form-textbox" required>
    <label for="form-password" class="form-label">Password</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-row">
    <input type="submit" value="Let's go!" class="form-submit">
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

You are looking for this kind of transition ?

Comment: no i want it to kind of fad in to the page just like the header that i have mad.

Comment: i don't see any code of header in html and you mean 1sec delay in transition ? @jack

Comment: yes i for got to put in the html but it is in the css code the 1s delay

Comment: i updated that 1s delay in the answer. Please make it as marked solution